# Is there a term for when people group 2 unrelated things they dislike into one entity?

Tags: terminology, vocabulary

I have seen this fallacy a lot of times when I'm having conversations with people.

For example - when someone assumes a person who leans towards the right on the political scale will definitely be misogynistic as well.

Conflation is *somewhat* correct, but it doesn't really include the 'dislike' aspect of it.

Is there a term for this phenomenon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like someone is ***stereotyping*** another person.

Macmillan:

> **[stereotype](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/stereotype_2#stereotype_11)**  ​*VERB*
>
> **1**   to believe that someone has a particular character only because this is what many people believe someone of their particular
> class, nationality, etc. must be like, and not because you know
> anything about their personality
>
> stereotype someone as something: Feminists are sometimes stereotyped
> as aggressive and unattractive.

Answer (score 0):

The [straw man fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man) is somewhat related to your description.